# Disable beta testing Android

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing, developer-console

About one month ago i upload my first App to the PlayStore and I reserved it only for beta testers. The App is now stable and I decide to move it from beta to production tab.

My question is: How can I disable App beta tester so they can rate my app? Is there a why to do that in the developer console or every single beta tester must leave the program from the playstore?

I found this button but I'm not sure what's going to happen if i click yes, 
Will all my users continue to use the app and exit the beta testing program without uninstalling and reinstalling the app? [image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 23):

For all those who have my own doubts I wanted to share my solution.

I clicked "YES" on the button that you see in the image, now all my beta testers are able to review and evaluate my app without having to uninstall the application or leave the beta test manually

hope it might be useful to someone in the future

Comment: It seems they changed the interface again, and currently (JUL 2019) it's not possible. There is no "disable beta testing" button anymore :-(

Comment: The button is still there, it's just called 'Remove Testers' now.

Answer (score 5):

Now the button is called `Pause track`.

It stops offering the `Join the beta` button on Google Play.

Comment: I see "Join the Beta" button on the store page even after pausing the track. Does anyone knows how to disable the whole Beta testing? (I don't want anyone to see "Join the Beta" button anymore... is it even possible?)

Comment: Just wait. It will eventually disappear. At least, that's what happened on the app I manage.

Comment: Even after pausing the track, if it is a Closed Track, your users will show still show the app as 'beta'. I removed them from the Testers and am hoping that it doesn't show as beta for them any longer.